# Google geocoding component filtering issue

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Google geocoding service works great for major cases, but there is one thing i found which seems strange to me.

I am sending address and components parameter in request for normalizing addresses. There are few addresses which could be wrong and should return ZERO_RESULT in response. But, just because i am passing country in components parameter, if the address does not exist it still returns the geocode for the country passed in components parameter, as mentioned in documentation here :
[Component filtering Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering)

My question is => Is that a correct behavior ? If you don't have results to put filter on, why should it geocode the whole country passed in component param ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is intended behavior. Have a look at this sentence in the documentation that you mentioned.

> If no matches are found, the geocoder returns a result that matches the filter itself.

So, if there is no matching address, the geocoder returns the filter itself which is a country in your case.

The most updated document that explains how the new geocoder uses a component filtering is the following:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq#trbl_component_filtering

I hope this helps!

Comment: -> Yes i got that point of returning geocode of country, but is it a behavior ? Because, if you don't have results to put filter on why should it geocode filter itself !! What i think is, The correct behavior should be that, we should be getting zero result instead of getting geocode for whole coutry passed in components param.

Comment: I think this is an intended behavior. It is documented by Google in their official documentation, so there is any doubt that they implemented this intentionally.